# Access values of column based on values of another column, Matlab table

Tags: matlab

I would like to access the values of column A based on the values of column B.
Now, I have done logical indexing when there is a single value of B.

```
certain_value = 4;

indices = (mytable.A == certain_value);

mytable(indices,:).B;
```

I could do logical operators if I wanted to compare with 2 or 3 values,

```
indices = ((mytable.A == 4) | mytable.A == 10);
```

but imagine that certain_value contains dozens of values.

My question is when I need something like:

```
certain_value = [4 10 214 20 30 2 6];
```

or longer.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `ismember` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ismember` instead of `==` to check if the value is a member of a set.

```
indices = ismember(mytable.A, certain_value);
```